# Mutate case_when nested conditional labelling

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data frame with multiple observations per ID. Each ID has performed many tests and for each test, has been classified into a tertile rank (top, mid, bottom) based on their test performance. This rank can vary at each time point.

Dummy df looks like this:

```
      df <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
        time = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
        test1_rank <- c("top", "top", "top", "top", "mid", "bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "top", "bottom", "bottom"),
test2_rank <- c("bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "top", "mid", "bottom", "top", "top", "top", "top", "bottom", "bottom"))
    
     ID  time `test1_rank <- ...` `test2_rank <- ...`
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               <chr>              
 1     1     1 top                 bottom             
 2     1     2 top                 bottom             
 3     1     3 top                 bottom             
 4     2     1 top                 top                
 5     2     2 mid                 mid                
 6     2     3 bottom              bottom             
 7     3     1 bottom              top                
 8     3     2 bottom              top                
 9     3     3 bottom              top                
10     4     1 top                 top                
11     4     2 bottom              bottom             
12     4     3 bottom              bottom
```

I want to create a new variable where I classify each individual based on how their rank changes with time for each test. Specifically, for each test:

- If rank is the same through all three time points, they get a label
  "stable" (can be stable(top) or stable(bottom) based on whether the
  rank is "top" or "bottom" across all time points).
- If the rank changes from top (time 1) to mid (time 2) to bottom (time 3), they
  get a label of  "gradual".
- If rank declines from top (time 1) to
  bottom (time 2 and time 3), they get a label of "rapid".
- Any other
  combination gets the label "Other".

Desired data frame:

```
  df2 <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                  time = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  test1_rank <- c("top", "top", "top", "top", "mid", "bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "top", "bottom", "bottom"),
test2_rank <- c("bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "top", "mid", "bottom", "top", "top", "top", "top", "bottom", "bottom"),
                  test1_rankgroup <- c("stable(top)", "stable(top)", "stable(top)", "gradual", "gradual", "gradual", "stable(bottom)", "stable(bottom)", "stable(bottom)", "rapid", "rapid", "rapid"), 
test2_rankgroup <- c("stable(bottom)", "stable(bottom)", "stable(bottom)", "gradual", "gradual", "gradual", "stable(top)", "stable(top)", "stable(top)", "rapid", "rapid", "rapid"))

        ID  time `test1_rank <- ...` `test2_rank <- ...` `test1_rankgroup <- ...` test2_ra…¹
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               <chr>               <chr>                    <chr>     
 1     1     1 top                 bottom              stable(top)              stable(bo…
 2     1     2 top                 bottom              stable(top)              stable(bo…
 3     1     3 top                 bottom              stable(top)              stable(bo…
 4     2     1 top                 top                 gradual                  gradual   
 5     2     2 mid                 mid                 gradual                  gradual   
 6     2     3 bottom              bottom              gradual                  gradual   
 7     3     1 bottom              top                 stable(bottom)           stable(to…
 8     3     2 bottom              top                 stable(bottom)           stable(to…
 9     3     3 bottom              top                 stable(bottom)           stable(to…
10     4     1 top                 top                 rapid                    rapid     
11     4     2 bottom              bottom              rapid                    rapid     
12     4     3 bottom              bottom              rapid                    rapid
```

What is the easiest way to solve this in `dplyr` using `mutate` and `case_when`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mutate` with `across` to apply your `case_when` to both of your ranked columns.

Your `case_when` can use `n_distinct` to see if the same value is held across your 3 time points. You can also include specific logic for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd values for a labelled group value.

The .default argument can be used for "other". The .by argument will perform the `mutate` grouped by `ID`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
             time = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
             test1_rank = c("top", "top", "top", "top", "mid", "bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "top", "bottom", "bottom"),
             test2_rank = c("bottom", "bottom", "bottom", "top", "mid", "bottom", "top", "top", "top", "top", "bottom", "bottom"))

df %>%
  mutate(across(-time,
               ~ case_when(n_distinct(.) == 1 ~ paste("stable", .),
                           .[1] == "top" & .[2] == "mid" & .[3] == "bottom" ~ "gradual",
                           .[1] == "top" & .[2] == "bottom" & .[3] == "bottom" ~ "rapid",
                           .default = "other"), 
               .names = "{.col}_group"),
         .by = ID)
```

**Output**

```
      ID  time test1_rank test2_rank test1_rank_group test2_rank_group
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>            <chr>           
 1     1     1 top        bottom     stable top       stable bottom   
 2     1     2 top        bottom     stable top       stable bottom   
 3     1     3 top        bottom     stable top       stable bottom   
 4     2     1 top        top        gradual          gradual         
 5     2     2 mid        mid        gradual          gradual         
 6     2     3 bottom     bottom     gradual          gradual         
 7     3     1 bottom     top        stable bottom    stable top      
 8     3     2 bottom     top        stable bottom    stable top      
 9     3     3 bottom     top        stable bottom    stable top      
10     4     1 top        top        rapid            rapid           
11     4     2 bottom     bottom     rapid            rapid           
12     4     3 bottom     bottom     rapid            rapid
```